# prevent parent UL from collapsing by clicking inner UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm embarrased to ask, but I'm running into a very primitive problem.

I have a very simple menu consisting of the follwing

```
<div id="mySidenav">
 <li>
   <a></a>
     <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </uL>
 </li>

 <li><a></a>
   <ul>
     <li><a></a>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

now I have very simple jquery to hide all the inner `UL`'s which is `$("#mySidenav li > ul").hide();`

To toggle the inner `ul`'s I use

```
 `$("#mySidenav li").click(function(){ 
    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
 })`
```

However, now I run into a problem. Whenever I click an inner-UL, the **parent** UL 'takes' the click and closes itself.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the event [bubbles up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) the DOM tree.

> If `list element A` is contained within `list element B`, and
>   element A is clicked, the click event fires for element A and then it
>   will bubble up and fire for element B. **This occurs because technically
>   you are clicking both elements.**

To prevent this behaviour, stop the propagation by using [`event.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$("#mySidenav li").click(function(event){
    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
     event.stopPropagation();
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav">
 <li>
   <a>parent 1</a>
     <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a>parent list 2</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a>list 4.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>list 4.1.1</li>
          <li>list 4.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added your code, but somehow, when I click `4.1` it still closes `parent list 2`

Comment: If I then click `parent list 2`... `4.1.` appears to be `openend`, showing `4.1.1`

Comment: Make sure that you specified `event` in your click handler cause the snippet works perfectly.